# How can i fixed Unity Burst Compiler falied running? (MAC mini M1)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd many try changed Unity Versions. But it`s not working... :(

BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.7.3) failed running

stdout:
Overriding backend due to platform constraints : 'burst-llvm-10'
Failed to determine iphoneos sdk installation path - /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk does not exist, and "xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path" failed with  xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'

stderr:

Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.3/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1446)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.3/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1312)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.3/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1287)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.3/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:543)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.3/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:208)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:541)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

Error building Player: BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.7.3) failed running

stdout:
Overriding backend due to platform constraints : 'burst-llvm-10'
Failed to determine iphoneos sdk installation path - /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk does not exist, and "xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path" failed with  xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphoneos'

stderr:

How Can i Fixed this...
i just want to build Unity Games on IOS
Please Help me .. Thank you all

Comment: Did you install iphoneos where it suggested